# Is There A Way To Make Reflections Act Similar To Cycles In EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, reflection

I have a low-poly glossy character in my scene, and when I render with cycles, each face is sliced into reflective triangles which looks very good.

But, when I try to render the scene in eevee, the faces reflect without being cut. Is there a way to make the character look similar to cycles in eevee?

Blend File: [image]
[image: 1]
<sup>EEVEE</sup>
[image: 2]
<sup>Cycles</sup>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's literally the quads to triangles part that you want... have you tried the Triangulate modifier?  You would not want keep normals (since you actually want the normals to differ across two triangles), and may need to experiment with the quad method to get the best results.

Comment: If you have suggestions on how to improve the answer I would like to hear them.  I could have tried it myself and posted screenshots as to the comparison but that would require access to a computer, downloading the example, and setting it up, when it really is a very simple and potentially helpful answer.  That said if there are any comments on things I -should- do to improve this answer I would love to hear them.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a *Light Probe* > *Reflection Cubemap* and a *Light Probe* > *Irradiance Volume* brings you close to the *Cycles* result. If you need any explanation on light probes, please ask.

[image]